# Creating Raid Disk from Existing Disk

Tags: linux, debian, raid, mdadm

I was going to follow the guide [here on arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_a_single_drive_system_to_RAID) to convert a single disk to a raid disk using mdadm.  The disk in question is a proxmox system disk.

My plan was as follows:

- Create the raid disk in a degraded state using mdadm and only the new disk.
- Boot into live image from USB
- Use `dd` to clone `/dev/sda` to `/dev/md0`
- Wipe `/dev/sda` and add it as the other raid1 member of `/dev/md0`.
- Edit `/etc/default/grub` on `/dev/md0` if necessary.
- Boot into system again from `/dev/md0`.

Would that work as expected?  Can I use `dd` on the disk or should I create the partitions of the exact same size then use `dd` for each partition instead?

Comment: If you're using a guide, why are you asking? Basically, it sounds like you've done your homework and the next step is to proceed with the process. But, make a backup first. Backed up data is data that is not lost.

Comment: @music2myear This is more a sanity check than anything.  Maybe someone sees this and points out an error I made.  I will be performing complete backups before proceeding, in the case I need to reinstall from scratch.